# Regular expression not working for name in asp.net mvc5 on client-side validation

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have asp.net mvc5 app and I am trying to validate regular expression that I have define in c# model class. I need to do client side validation for individual input field as user goes along filling form. I have test expression on online site and it correct. Doesn't matter whatever I say in field, it turn to red and showing error message.

### model

```
[StringLength(50)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Title")]
[RegularExpression("(/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i)", ErrorMessage = "Only Allowed Alphabet Character In Title"
[Display(Name = "Title")]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

### html out-put

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field Title must be a string with a maximum length of 50." data-val-length-max="50" data-val-regex="Only Allowed Alphabet Character In Title" data-val-regex-pattern="(/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i)" data-val-required="Required Title" id="Title" name="Title" value="" type="text">
```

### JavaScript

```
 $(function () {

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse();

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#CreateStudentProfileForm");


});



$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").find("input,textarea,select").on('input', function () {

        var _currentElement = $(this).attr('id');

        var v = $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").validate().element("#" + _currentElement);

        alert("va   " + v);
    });

});
```

my javaScript inside the partial-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the anaswer as below;

```
 [MaxLength(50)]
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Title")]
 [RegularExpression("(^[a-z ,.'-]+$)", ErrorMessage = "Only Allowed Alphabet Character In Title")]
 [Display(Name = "Title")]
 public string Title { get; set; }
```

...

```
 $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").find("input,textarea,select").on('input', function () {

        var _currentElement = $(this).attr('id');

        var v = $("#CreateStudentProfileForm").validate().element("#" + _currentElement);
});
```